# Unknown database TABLE_NAME in php

Tags: php, database-connection

I am using PHP version 7.3.12 along with PHPMyAdmin and WAMP.

[image: Screenshot of databases.]

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "employee_management";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName) or die("Database connection failed");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        var_dump($row['eid']);
    }
}
```

I have already created the db but the I get unknown database error.

I only get this error with what I created, not the others that have already existed.

I have looked at all posts related to this error and tried re-downloading everything, and change the db.

However, I have not got it fixed even thought I have spent days to figure this out.

Comment: Are you sure you have only one database? Some dev tools install MySQL and MariaDB and you may be inadvertently using two DBs without realizing it.

Comment: I used mysql console in wamp to import the table

Comment: Have you tried turning on error reporting in PHP? It might contain something useful.

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Also, as I understand it, you might have 2 instances of MySQL running.
You could try to run a query like this to get all tables in the database your php script connects to (if you might got 2 databases running):

SHOW TABLES from employee_management